# After migrating to Kubernetes, PHP kernel response times increased

Tags: php, kubernetes

There is an application written in PHP Symphony. The application is stateless, all code and statics are inside the application container. We moved it from docker to kubernetes, but after testing requests to it, we found that the kernel.responce parameter has grown noticeably:

[Symphony Profiler Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3vwNc.png)

While the request is simple, the pod with the application is minimally loaded and does not reach the load limit. The application accesses only Redis inside K8s and standalone PostgreSQL on a dedicated server and there are no problems in connection speed to them. What could be the problem with the kernel.responce parameter for PHP applications inside K8s?